# Sheep farmers and PCP addicts

Tags: wordplay, enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, story

I was meeting a small group of people in Griffith Park one afternoon. Two of the group were running late. They were carpooling together and we knew it would still be a while before they showed up, so we decided to get to know each other a little bit before the remaining two arrived.

Here's what I learned about everyone who was present.

> **Rick** used to be a sheep farmer, but recently got into the computer memory business. He has quite a bad temper – he once broke down a competitor's door after a big argument.
>
> **Chad** sells all kinds of useful stuff for the home, from nail cutters to hedge trimmers. He's doing quite well for himself and recently purchased a sailing ship.
>
> **Al** is a member of a prominent motorcycle club and enjoys Dan Brown books. He recently managed to kick his years-long PCP addiction after a powerful religious experience.
>
> **Ken** enjoys history, card games and listening to New Orleans rhythms. He recently started hosting an annual competition for Elvis impersonators.
>
> **Larry** recently purchased fifty acres of land up in Minnesota. He has always dreamt of a house by the water.
>
> **Don** is a mighty friendly fellow who works at Disney. He enjoys Chinese cuisine and taking long baths.

Based on the information provided, guess the **make and model of the car** in which the missing two people are travelling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that their car is a

> Dodge Charger.

Each of the six people we've been told about

> clues a single word associated with each bit of the information we're given about them, beginning with the same letter as their name.

Rick

> RAM (ram = male sheep, RAM computer memory, battering ram)

Chad

> CLIP/CLIPPER (nail clippers, hedge clippers, clipper ships)

Al

> ANGEL (Hell's Angels, Angels & Demons, angel dust, perhaps an encounter with an angel)

Ken

> KING (monarchs are prominent in historical work, kings in a deck of cards, maybe Earl King or King Oliver, "the King")

Larry

> LAKE? (Minnesota is sometimes called "the land of 10000 lakes", lakeside house?)

Don

> DUCK ("duck" as a friendly term of address in Northern England?, Donald Duck, Peking duck, ... just the fact that ducks live in the water?)

All of these

> are names, or closely related to names, of major league sports teams in Los Angeles (where Griffith Park is located).

So the other two

> are probably two from {Dodgers, Galaxy, Sparks, Chargers}. I think the only pair that gives us a vehicle make and model is DODGE CHARGER.